# Why is xterm not found in my C shell and how can I add it as I find it in TERM

Tags: path, xterm, csh

I get this error:

> X terminal for some input / output,
>   please make sure "xterm" command can be found in
>   your PATH environment

When I

```
echo $TERM
```

I get `xterm`. But `xterm` cannot be found on my Linux system when I search for, so I can't put path to my C shell.

Comment: It depends on the system: Debian-based (sudo apt-get install xterm), Redhat (sudo dnf install xterm), Arch (sudo pacman -Sy xterm), Mageia and OpenSUSE differ as well.

Answer (score 1):

`xterm` is just the behavior of your terminal. This has to do with what, say, the `clear` program sends to your screen when you run it. If you actually want to run the `xterm` program, you'll have to install it.

Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install xterm
```

Red Hat (thanks [Thomas Dickey](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/105132/thomas-dickey) for the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579504/why-is-xterm-not-found-in-my-c-shell-and-how-can-i-add-it-as-i-find-it-in-term#comment1078755_579504)):

```
sudo dnf install xterm
```

and Arch Linux (another from the comment):

```
sudo pacman -Sy xterm
```